# Set Theory Proof $A=B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A$ be the set of all integers $x$ such that $x = 2k$ for some integer $k$

Let $B$ be the set of all integers $x$ such that $x = 2k+2$ for some integer $k$

Give a formal proof that $A = B$.

Comment: Show that any element from set A is also in set B. Then show that any element from set B is also in set A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that both $A\subset B$ and $B\subset A$.

Fix $x \in A$. Then we can write $x=2k$ for some $k$, which means we could also write $x=2k=2k-2+2=2(k-1)+2$. Thus $x\in B$, because for $k'=k-1$ we can write $x=2k'+2$.

This proves one direction, that $A\subset B$. The other direction is nearly identical.

Answer (score 4):

You need to show us some effort in the future.

First, to show two sets are equal, we normally pick an element of the first set, show it is contained in the second, then pick an element in the second, and show it is contained in the first.

If we suppose $x \in A$, then $x=2k$ for some integer $k$. Since $x = 2k$, $x = 2(k-1)+2$, and since $k-1$ is an integer, $x \in B$. Thus, $A \subseteq B$.

I leave the proof of $B \subseteq A$ to you.